# How to transpoze of the table with measure in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a problem as below. How can i write a dax?

[image]

Comment: In a matrix visual or the underlying data table?

Comment: Actually I prefer in a matrix, because My data model is a little complex.